# help using perl dbi with mysql to query a remote database

Tags: mysql, perl

I need help figuring out this configuration and the use of mysql perl DBI.

My local connection works fine, but once I try to query a remote host db I am getting errors. 
I know my setup to the remote db works as I can do the following from a shell:

**WORKS:**

```
$ mysql -u foo-man -pmypa55w0rd --database abc -h abc123.name.locale --port 3306 -ss -e "select UUID()"
```

From using the perl DBI, **localhost** works too:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=test;host=localhost:port=3306;user=root");
```

But using perl DBI, querying a remote database, NO luck.

**DOESN'T WORK:**

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=abc;host=abc123.name.locale;port=3306;user=foo-man,password=mypa55w0rd");
```

nor using the IP for example:

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=abc;host=123.567.89.10;port=3306;user=foo-man,password=mypa55w0rd");
```

Comment: What error message do you get from `$DBI::errstr`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use

```
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=abc;host=abc123.name.locale;port=3306",
                       'foo-man', 'mypa55w0rd');
```

But it would probably also work if you changed the comma after the username to a semicolon.